# POST request on HTML form does nothing when submitting

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for hours. I'm creating a simple API as a Rails beginner, and so far I have the following routes:

```
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                             cats GET    /cats(.:format)                                                                          cats#index
                                  POST   /cats(.:format)                                                                          cats#create
                          new_cat GET    /cats/new(.:format)                                                                      cats#new
                         edit_cat GET    /cats/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 cats#edit
                              cat GET    /cats/:id(.:format)                                                                      cats#show
                                  PATCH  /cats/:id(.:format)                                                                      cats#update
                                  PUT    /cats/:id(.:format)                                                                      cats#update
                                  DELETE /cats/:id(.:format)                                                                      cats#destroy
```

I'm trying to create a form to generate a new cat. I originally created a full form with buttons and dropdown menus, but boiling it down to the issue, when I create a form under `new.html` with the following:

```html
<h2>Submit a cat</h2>

<form action="/cats" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

the submit button does nothing. Viewing my requests on the server, it only shows the get request. My controller is set up with the following:

```
class CatsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @cats = Cat.all 
    render :index    
end

def show
    @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])
    render :show
end

def create
#    @cat = Cat.new(params[:cat])
    render json: "creating"
end

def new
    render :new
end
end
```

Does anyone know why the submit button is doing nothing?

Comment: Properly because the cat form is empty so params[:cat] has nothing in it?

Comment: Use `form_with` (Rails 5.1+) or `form_tag` in previous versions to create a form with a authenticity token. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is because Postman blocks forms in the preview window (see: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5926)